# Keep only the first sequence of a column

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataset where level_no may repeat (see dput below). I only want to keep the "first round" of data, so as to speak. For example, ID = 1 has level_no 0,1,2,3,1, I want to keep only the first round.

[image: Some level no may start from 0, 1, 2]

So far, I'm using distinct to remove the subsequent rounds but I'm not sure if this is the correct approach.

```r
puzzleData_mandatory %>% arrange(ID, total_played_time) %>% select(ID, level_no, total_played_time) %>% 
  distinct(.keep_all = TRUE, ID, level_no)
```

[image: Output from Distinct]

```r
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), level_no = c(0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, NA), total_played_time = c(285.54, 542.94, 
856.8, 1129.1, 1226.98, 282.28, 457.42, 947.78, 1073.8, 161.66, 
293.38, 548.26, 682.66, 818.18, 976.86, 1008.76, 1019.34, 59.06, 
93.14, 223.1, 485.24, 644.2, 2002.74, 2249.74, 2417.84, 2481.99, 
2614.9, 2818.64, 2913.61, 3039.14, 3057.44, 3217.52, 3359.48, 
3480.78, 3638.04, 3764.88, 3883.16, 4025.9, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-39L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you need only the first level, remove the `level_no` from `distinct` i.e. `distinct(.keep_all = TRUE, ID)`

Comment: Or may also use `slice_min/group_by` `puzzleData_mandatory %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice_min(n = 1, order_by = total_played_time) %>% ungroup`

Answer (score 1):

If you want all of the rows where the level_no is minimum for an ID, then you can do this

```
puzzledata %>% arrange(level_no) %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice_min(level_no)
```

If you want only one row per ID, where you take the row with the minimum total_played_time within the level_no that is minimum, you can do this

```
puzzleData_mandatory %>% 
  arrange(ID, level_no, total_played_time) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(row_number()==1)
```

If you want the first increasing sequence of level_no for each id, you can do this:

```
data %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(change=sign(level_no -lag(level_no)),
         change=if_else(is.na(change),1,change),
         id = data.table::rleid(change)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(id==1) %>% 
  select(1:3)
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I want. I want to remove a specific sequence if it happens more than once. For example, a user played all three levels (0,1,2,3). I want to remove all rows were the user may have played again---in the same pattern (0,1,2,3). Does that make sense?

Comment: but in your example you have for ID=1, you have 0,1,2,3,1, and you seem to want to remove the fifth row, the one with the second instance of "1".  But that is different than removing a "specific sequence if it happens more than once".. . So specifically for user=1, which rows do you want to remain?  only 0,1,2,3, or do you want to retain all rows for user=1?

Comment: I've guessed that you want the first increasing sequence of level_no for each ID, and added that has a third option